# I dont understand how this for loop works

Tags: java, for-loop, increment

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20-i; i+=3) {

     System.out.println(--i);
}
```

Why is the initial value **-1** and how is it incrementing that value?

Answer (score 5):

`--i` means subtract 1 from `i` before using it. If you'd put `i--` then it'd mean take the value of `i` and then subtract 1 *after* using it.

In each loop you are adding 3, but then you are subtracting 1 before you use the value.  So in other words you are in effect only really adding 2. The values of `i` you are using are: `-1, 1, 3, 5, 7` which is a bit confusing!

**EDIT:** Just to add, it does stop at that point, because the next time through the loop you'd have `7+3` which `=10` and `10 !< 20-10` so it can't do that iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have --i, if you had i-- the first output would be 0.

--i will take one off the answer as ++i will add one to the answer.

So, whatever output your loop is constructing, 1 will always be deducted from the final output because of the --i.

If you had i-- it would still deduct one from the final answer, but it would what until the loop had ended to deduct 1.

Comment: No the question is why is it -1 itself? i cant get the values when i do it by hand.

Comment: Because i=0 on the first loop. Then when it tries to output you are saying --i, so the answer is 0-1 = -1. It wont increment the +=3 until the second time around the loop

Answer (score 1):

Inside the println you are displaying --i.  -- decrements the value of i.  To start with in the loop i = 0.

When you decrement 0 you get -1.

The for loop itself is adding to i with the i+=3 on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

--i is pre decrement operator. First decrements the value in i and then access it to print, so value is -1

i-- is post decrement operator. First access value in i and then decrements value, so value will be 0

Answer (score 1):

Your loop variable is bing modified both in the for statement and in the body as well. First the expression `--i` is evaluated, yielding -1. Then the for statement modifies it by adding 3. Next time through the loop it should take away 1 more before printing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

--i first decrements the value of i and the -1 printed as first value. At the end of each cycle i is incremented by 3.

Then i goes in each cycle as
i -> -1 -> 2
i -> 1 -> 4
until
i -> 7 -> 10

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop, first you have an assignment - in this case `i = 0;` - this is the starting value of i. 
The next part is the condition - here `i < 20 - i` - this will be checked at each step of the loop before entering it.
The third part has the condition - `i += 3` This will increment i by 3 in each iteration.

So..
Now you have `i = 0` to start with, `i < 20 -i` is `true`, so it enters the loop, 
and it executes the statement `System.out.println(--i);`
This is the pre decrement operator, so it decrements i by one, and then prints it.

This is repeated as long as the condition `i < 20 -i` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

**--i**  is pre decrements operator. it first decrease  the value in i with 1 and then  print it ,
so if the value of i is currently is 0 the 1st this value is reduced by 1 that means `i==i-1` then print it `i=-1`